# How to delete from a container of strings of paths, duplicate filenames together with their different paths?

Tags: python, path, duplicates, containers

I would need to delete duplicates in a list (or set) of files that will be copied to a folder specifically created by date in Python.

What I need is to locate the duplicate already in the starting list, in the last part of the file path '/home/user/text.txt', then to delete the whole path from the list, so that the starting list (or set) of files that will be copied does not have those duplicates that may exist in the file system and that the number of elements to be copied, represented in the starting container, is eventually the same as the number of files actually copied in the destination folder.

I tried to reach this goal also through the option `key` of `sorted()`:

```
set_path_filename_without_duplicates = sorted(set_path_filename,
                                              key=lambda x: x.split()[1])
```

and I get the error `IndexError: list index out of range`

At the moment I don't know what to do yet, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please add some examples of the data in the list (or set) of files to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you have a list of a lot of files. There may be duplicates of the files in the list, but also the same file may be many places?

If so the following should work to return only one path per unique filename.

```
import os
list_of_filepaths=['root/dir/some_pic.jpeg',
               'root/dir/some_pic2.jpeg',
               'root/documents/budget.excl',
               'root/Music/audio.mp3',
               'root/dir/some_pic.jpeg',
               'root/otherfolder/some_pic.jpeg']

dict_of_files={os.path.basename(file):file for file in list_of_filepaths}
files=list(set(dict_of_files.keys()))
unique_files=[dict_of_files[file] for file in files]

In [16]: unique_files
Out[16]: 
['root/dir/some_pic2.jpeg',
 'root/documents/budget.excl',
 'root/Music/audio.mp3',
 'root/otherfolder/some_pic.jpeg']
```